# Java Applet not displaying image (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, applet

I'm trying to get a basic Java applet displaying a simple image up and running but for some reason (I suspect a path issue or a IntelliJ setting I'm not familiar with) it's not showing up.

Here's my code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;


public class Main extends Applet{

    private Image logo;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        logo = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "image.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        g.drawImage(logo, 10, 10, this);
    }
}
```

The image is located in the same directory as the code itself.

[image: intellij file browser]

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: The `documentBase` refers to the "page" that the applet was loaded from

Comment: So what do you suggest? Is there a way to get this working if I run it in IntelliJ?

Comment: You should figure out what `documentBase` actually is (or where it points to in this case). A better solution would be to embedded the image within the resulting Jar and use `getClass().getResource(...)`

Comment: I'd suggest not using applets if you can avoid it and if you can't use a `JApplet` over `Applet`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting that image in a folder 'Resources' in your project.
Also right click that folder -> Mark as Resources.  I did this  many times and it worked

Comment: But this would embed the image as an embedded resource, it would still not be accessible via `getDocumentBase` as that assumes the resources resides on the webserver